# How many unique, continuous and exhaustive paths exist for adjacent squares in a 3 x 3 lattice?

Tags: combinatorics

I get 8*(4-1)+(8–2)=30 paths for the 3 x 3 lattice.  Eight continuous and exhaustive paths (of varied symmetries) start from each of the four corner squares, duplicating half the paths from two of the four corners.  The four mid-side squares yield no exhaustive path termini.  Paths from the center square duplicate corners’ paths two out of eight times, when the latter end in the center.

Comment: So, you're counting a path, and the reverse of that path, to be the same?

Comment: Yes.  The path is the same, starting at either end.